# Mantine disable button animation on click?

Tags: mantine

I would like to disable the button animation on the click. As can be seen [here](https://mantine.dev/core/button/), when clicking on the button, the button moves. Is there an easy way to disable this?

Answer (score 4):

```
<Button styles={{ root: { ':active': { transform: 'none' } } }}>test</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or globally:

```
     <MantineProvider
        theme={{
          components: {
            Button: {
              styles: {
                root: { ":active": { transform: "none" } },
              },
            },
          },
        }}
      >
        {...app}
      </MantineProvider>
```

Answer (score -1):

with in code you can use this

button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);